# Can we use custom metadata type in a object link formula?

Tags: formula, custom-metadata, custom-link

When i try to create a formual field on an object to diplay my custom metadata type, everything is working with this syntax :

```
$CustomMetadata.CustomMetadataObject__mdt.Record.Value__c
```

But when i try to create an Object link (from "**Buttons, Links and Actions**" in object manager) including this CustomMetadata Type I have an error :

**The link formula:**

```
/one/one.app#/alohaRedirect/0MI/e?territoryModelId={$CustomMetadata.CustomMetadataObject__mdt.Record.Value__c}&Name={!Cercle__c.Name}
```

**The error :**

> Error: Field
> $CustomMetadata.CustomMetadataObject__mdt.Record.Value__c does
> not exist. Check spelling.

Any idea if this is possible ton include CMT in object link ?

Comment: Still no answer..! Please upvote this idea - https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdl3hUAB/allow-custom-metadata-types-to-be-referenced-in-custom-buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot refer custom metadata type in custom links.  Custom metadata type can be referred only in Formulas, Default Values, and Validation Rules.

Check more details [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/custom_metadata_types_dec/cmt_formulas).

Thanks